# How do I migrate guests running on Xen to KVM?

Tags: xen, kvm-virtualization, migration

Is it possible to migrate some Xen DomU guests on an Debian Etch Dom0 running Xen 3.2.1?

The guests are various versions of Ubuntu 8.04+ or Debian.

The new machine is Ubuntu 10.04 running kvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it is only possible for Red Hat, as they are developing the virt-v2v tool, if an automated method is what you are looking for. See this [video](http://cdn.kaltura.com/p/311322/sp/31132200/flvclipper/entry_id//flavor/1/version/0/width/1280/height/720/a.flv), where they demonstrate how easy it is.

Another option is to do everything by hand. This (2) blog post describes how to do it step-by-step for RHEL guests. I would guess it is fairly similar for Ubuntu guests.

If you don't care about network and IO performance, you can just make a domain.xml, the guest config file that contains network card info, partitions, and so on, as if the Xen guest was a KVM guest.

As long as you have enabled a kernel that supports KVM in the guest, KVM will run it in QEMU mode. Meaning without the optimized network and disk drivers.

To see how you create a domain.xml file see here (3) and here(4).

(2) http://gloudemans.info/migrate-paravirtualized-xen-to-kvm-under-rhel/

(3) http://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html

(4) http://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#xmlconfig

Comment: Outstanding, thank you!  I'm already pretty much committed to Ubuntu for the host, so hopefully I can use your second suggestion to run the less important VMs until I can rebuild them from scratch under KVM.

Comment: Yes, do that. To get an idea how the domain.xml looks like, create a guest that is as similar to the one you want to migrate, and copy/modify that domain.xml to fir the new guest.

Comment: http://www.gloudemans.info/migrate-paravirtualized-xen-to-kvm-under-rhel/ is the article in (2), URL above doesn't work (requires addition of www. prefix as well as the removal of the space). Thanks @maj!